# Dynamic EC2 Bucket Options for Fog/Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, fog

I have a Rails3 application which uses Carrierwave and Fog to store data to Amazon's S3.  This application I am building requires that I allow each user to have their own secure EC2 bucket.  The premise of the application is that the user will create a account (devise) and I will generate a storage bucket just for that user under my application's EC2 User and Password.  Based on the current documentation, I have not seen a way to have multiple buckets as this is configured in the FOG YML.  I would like to ask for alternatives to set this FOG_DIRECTORY dynamically based on the user attributes.

I know there is a way to manage dynamic folders, but this will not work as I need dedicated buckets by user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate why you can't use dynamic folders? Do your users need direct access, other than through your app? If not, signed urls work great.

Comment: Currently the FOG Directory is set in my fog yml.  I would like to store a bucket id at a user level.  When I need to store some information, I will look up the user and find the bucket id to use. My issue is how to set this fog directory outside of the configuration yml?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your buckets already exist.
Try the following:

```
#config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  #...other configuration stuff...
  config.fog_directory = 'null.example.com'

  config.fog_host = proc do
    proc do |file|
      uploader = file.instance_variable_get :@uploader
      "http://#{uploader.fog_directory}"
    end
  end
end
```

Note the nested procs, as of the writing of the this answer the documentation for carrierwave is incorrect. If you want the fog_host to be dynamic, you have to wrap the proc so that the carrierwave configuration class does the right thing.

Even though the fog_directory is set dynamically later. Test frameworks and such complain if something is not set in the initializer(it things work correctly the setting is always overridden).

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb

before_filter :set_bucket

def set_bucket
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_directory = "#{current_user.id}.bucket.example.com"
  end
end
```

Change the set_bucket function to suit your bucket naming convention.

You can add some conditional logic if you want a fixed bucket in development rather than a bucket per user.

Also [this](http://blog.29steps.co.uk/post/28277542161/custom-carrierwave-uploader-with-dynamic-user-s3) blog post outlines another approach.